# Magento 2 When Adding a product to cart programmatically , mini cart product price become zero($0.00)

Tags: php, magento2

I have created one module for add product to cart with custom options in loop programmatically. when we run this controller code, it will display products with price in cart page but in mini cart display product price  $0.00.
My controller code is given below.

```
<?php

namespace Mageniks\Customaddtocart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Addtocart extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;
    protected $_productloader;
    protected $cartRepository;
    protected $quoteManagement;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $quoteFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
                                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
                                PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
                                \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
                                \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
                                \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
                                \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    protected function addProduct($products)
    {
         // Note : $products peramater contain all product information.
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        foreach($products as $params)
        {
            $cartparams = array();          
           $productId = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($params['sku']);     
           $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
            if (!$product) {
                return false;
            }
            $cartparams['product'] = $product->getId();            
            $customOptions = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

                foreach ($customOptions as $option) 
                {
                    if($option['title'] == "option1")
                    {                       
                            $cartparams['options'][$option['option_id']] = "Color : black";
                    }
                    else if($option['title'] == "option2")
                    {


                            $cartparams['options'][$option['option_id']] = "Color : white";


                    }else
                    {
                        $cartparams['options'][$option['option_id']] = "";
                    }
                }



            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $cartparams['qty'] = $params['qty'];
            } else {
                $cartparams['qty'] = 1;
            }
            try {


                 $this->cart->addProduct($product, $cartparams);


            }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                    );
                } else {
                    $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(
                            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                        );
                    }
                }

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            }
            unset($params['product']);


        }
         $this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
         $this->cart->save();
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have debug all the things but mini cart price can not changed.It display zero after add to cart in cart page.

Can you please help me for solve this issue ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have got the solution of this problem. Here is my updated code.

```
<?php

namespace Mageniks\Customaddtocart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Addtocart extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;
    protected $_productloader;
    protected $cartRepository;
    protected $quoteManagement;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $quoteFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
                                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
                                PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
                                \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
                                \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
                                \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
                                \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    protected function addProduct($products)
    {
         // Note : $products peramater contain all product information.
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        foreach($products as $params)
        {
            $cartparams = array();          
           $productId = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($params['sku']);     
           $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
            if (!$product) {
                return false;
            }
            $cartparams['product'] = $product->getId();            
            $customOptions = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

                foreach ($customOptions as $option) 
                {
                    if($option['title'] == "option1")
                    {                       
                            $cartparams['options'][$option['option_id']] = "Color : black";
                    }
                    else if($option['title'] == "option2")
                    {


                            $cartparams['options'][$option['option_id']] = "Color : white";


                    }else
                    {
                        $cartparams['options'][$option['option_id']] = "";
                    }
                }



            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $cartparams['qty'] = $params['qty'];
            } else {
                $cartparams['qty'] = 1;
            }
            try {


                $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                $request->setData($cartparams);
                $this->cart->addProduct($product,$request);

            }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                    );
                } else {
                    $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(
                            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                        );
                    }
                }

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            }
            unset($params['product']);


        }
         $this->cart->save();
         $quote->save();
         $quote->collectTotals(); 
         $this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();


        return true;
    }

}
```

After so much google or debugging i have found the solution. I have just change the cart addProduct method in params set as dataobject. Please check below.

```
$request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$request->setData($cartparams);
$this->cart->addProduct($product,$request);
```

$cartparams contain product qty, custom options .. etc.
$cartparams pass into dataobject and then pass it to cart addProduct method and It's worked for me.